# jQuery select with partial name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like the count the element on the page with the name :

- MyElement_1
- MyElement_2

Then I'd like get element MyElement

Thanks,

Comment: Could you post your html please.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var elements = $('[name^=MyElement]');
var length = elements.length;
```

If you want some more advanced filtering, you can filter all the dom nodes by matching your own rules :

```
var elements = $('[name]').filter(function(){
    return /^MyElement_\d+$/.test($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 15):

Use [`starts with selector`:](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('[name^="MyElement"]').length
```

Answer (score 2):

better using

```
$('input[name$="name"]')
```

Comment: This will select `input` elements whose `name` attribute value **ends with** `name`, not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

To find an element by the name attribute, use:

```
$('[name=something]');
```

use *=, ^=, etc. to be more or less specific in the search term. Look at the [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) page for more info on how to use them.

The exaple above returns all elements that match. Suffix this with .length and you'll get the number of elements that are found, like so:

```
 $('[name=something]').length;
```