# Find an element by partial ID in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an element on my page, where i only will know part of its `id`, e.g. `_moComments_`:

```
id="MainContent_listSelectedDays_listDayBanks_0_moComments_0"
```

How can i find an element by partial id (e.g. using jQuery)?

**For example [(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/bjKzu/2/)**:

```
<input type="text" id="MainContent_listSelectedDays_listDayBanks_0_moComments_0">
```

with script

```
$('[id=_moComments_]').val("Found it");
```

**Bonus Reading**

- [jQuery selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [jQuery select with partial name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873782/jqquery-select-with-partial-name)
- [Making partial matches with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488942/how-can-i-make-partial-matches-with-jquery)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You could use the ["Attribute Contains Selector"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('[id*="_moComments_"]')
```

However you'd probably be better off by simply adding a class or a custom `[data-*]` attribute and selecting based on that.