# Set a new value for HiddenField in JavaScript vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net

How set a new value for HiddenField in java script. My Hidden field and button is like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField Id="tz" runat="server" Visible ="false"/>
<asp:Button ID="BTN_Export" runat="server" Text="Export to *.xlsx" onClientClick="SetValue();"/>
```

And my java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SetValue() {
            document.getElementById('tz').value = "testing !!!!!";
        }
    </script>
```

When i try to pun a new value to HiddenField get me error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use client id of hidden field, when asp.net control is rendered its id is slightly changed. or you can get client id in JS using regex or as:

document.getElementById('<%= tz.ClientID %>').value

OR

[Get asp.net control with partial id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749188/find-an-element-by-partial-id-in-jquery)