# How to select text of a dropdown list which id ends with some string in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select the text of dropdown list in which id ends with string `SelectId`

if the id is a fixed one like `fixedid`, it can be achieved by

```
var val = $('#fixedid :selected').text();
```

But, in my case, I know only some end text of that id and that is `SelectId`

I have tried below code but it failed

```
$('[id$="SelectId"]').text()
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:-[Find an element by partial ID in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749188/find-an-element-by-partial-id-in-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find an element by partial ID in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749188/find-an-element-by-partial-id-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the selected option within it for getting text content of selected option.

```
$('[id$="SelectId"] :selected').text()
//-----------------^^^^^^^^^^^-------
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work to get the option.

```
$("select[id$='SelectId'] option:selected").text()
```

Comment: Anybody care to tell me what it wrong with this approach when down voting?